# Shell Script : How to check if variable is null or no

Tags: string, bash, shell, is-empty

I want to check if variable is null or no.

My code is :

```
    list_Data="2018-01-15 10:00:00.000|zQfrkkiabiPZ||04|
            2018-01-15 10:00:00.000|zQgKLANvbRWg||04|
            2018-01-15 10:00:00.000|zQgTEbJjWGjf||01|
            2018-01-15 10:00:00.000|zQgwF1YJLnAT||01|"

    echo "list_Data"

    if [[ -z "list_Data" ]]
    then
    echo "not Empty"
    else
    echo "empty"
    fi
```

The Output is :

```
2018-01-15 10:00:00.000|zQfrkkiabiPZ||04|
2018-01-15 10:00:00.000|zQgKLANvbRWg||04|
2018-01-15 10:00:00.000|zQgTEbJjWGjf||01|
2018-01-15 10:00:00.000|zQgwF1YJLnAT||01|
empty
```

The problem that the varible contain values but i have always empty message please help.

Comment: Your logic is upside down, `-z` is true when the string is empty.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try following, you should change from `-z` to `-n` as follows and add `$` to your variable too.

```
if [[ -n "$list_Data" ]]
then
    echo "not Empty"
else
    echo "empty"
fi
```

***Explanation:*** From `man test` page as follows(It checks if a variable is having any value or not. If it has any value then condition is TRUE, if not then it is FALSE.)

> ```
>    -n STRING
>           the length of STRING is nonzero
> ```

Answer (score 23):

```
if [[ -z "$list_Data" ]]
then
  echo "Empty"
else
  echo "Not empty"
fi
```

Try it like this.  (Added `$` and switched cases.)

Answer (score 10):

You can use any of the below in Bash shell find out if a variable has NULL value OR not

```
my_var="DragonBallz"
if [ -z "$my_var" ]
then
      echo "\$my_var is NULL"
else
      echo "\$my_var is NOT NULL"
fi
```

(or)

```
my_var=""
if test -z "$my_var" 
then
      echo "\$my_var is NULL"
else
      echo "\$my_var is NOT NULL"
fi
```

(or)

```
[ -z "$my_var" ] && echo "NULL"
[ -z "$my_var" ] && echo "NULL" || echo "Not NULL"
```

(or)

```
[[ -z "$my_var" ]] && echo "NULL"
[[ -z "$my_var" ]] && echo "NULL" || echo "Not NULL"
```

(or)

```
var="$1"
if [ ! -n "$var" ]
then
    echo "$0 - Error \$var not set or NULL"
else
    echo "\$var set and now starting $0 shell script..."
fi
```

Answer (score 9):

I wasn't expecting this solution, when all above solutions failed for me, this one worked for me

```
if [[ "$is_always_execute" == null ]];
then
    is_always_execute=false;
fi
```